# could not access the github.com when switch the dns server to 8.8.8.8

Tags: network, dns

when I tried to switch the dns server to 8.8.8.8, I found sometimes could not access the github.com, the browser shows error:

```
This site can’t be reachedThe connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

it may be the dns resolve failed! so I using this command to check but seems work fine:

```
$ dig www.github.com                                                                                                                                                                                                             ‹ruby-2.7.2›

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.github.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28429
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.github.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.github.com.     3242    IN  CNAME   github.com.
github.com.     43  IN  A   20.205.243.166

;; Query time: 45 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 02 13:07:04 CST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73
```

why did this happen? is it possible to resolve this issue? This is how I set the dns in macOS 13.4.1 :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried 8.8.4.4? (Google's other server.) Or OpenDNS or 1.1.1.1? It could be just a temporary issue.

Comment: My guess would be the Great Firewall of China. 8.8.8.8 is Google.